# Replacing a letter in a string with a char

Tags: java

```
String lower = Name.toLowerCase();
int a = Name.indexOf(" ",0);
String first = lower.substring(0, a);
String last = lower.substring(a+1);
char f = first.charAt(0);
char l = last.charAt(0);
f = Character.toUpperCase(f);
l = Character.toUpperCase(l);
String newname = last +" "+ first;
System.out.println(newname);
```

i want to take variables F and L and replace the lowercase first letters in last and first so they will be uppercase. How can I do this? i want to just replace the first letter in the last and first name with the char first and last

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to do what i think you are, you should consider using the [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library, then look at:

[WordUtils.capitalize](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)

obviously, this is also open source, so for the best solution to your homework i'd take a look at the source code.

However, if i were writing it from scratch (and optimum performance wasn't the goal) here's how i would approach it:

```
public String capitalize(String input)
{
    // 1. split on the negated 'word' matcher (regular expressions)
    String[] words = input.toLowerCase().split("\\W");
    StringBuffer end = new StringBuffer();
    for (String word : words)
    {
        if (word.length == 0)
            continue;
        end.append(" ");
        end.append(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)));
        end.append(word.substring(1));
    }
    // delete the first space character
    return end.deleteCharAt(0).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
You could also use a string tokenizer to get the names as in:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(Name);
String fullName = "";
String currentName;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    /* add spaces between each name */
    if(fullName != "") fullName += " ";
    currentName = st.nextToken();
    fullName += currentName.substring(0,0).toUpperCase() + currentName.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: It will replace every oldChar by newChar

Comment: @Colin: I thought replaceAll was the one that replaced all but after checking the API, I see you're right. Either way, replace is not the best option.  Answer adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

While there's more efficient ways of doing this, you almost got it. You'd just need to concatenate the uppercase chars with the first and last name, bar the first character.

```
 String newname = "" + l + last.subString(1) + " " + f + first.subString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = "firstname lastname";
//match with letter in beginning or a letter after a space
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^\\w| \\w").matcher(name);
StringBuffer b=new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find())
    matcher.appendReplacement(b,matcher.group().toUpperCase());
matcher.appendTail(b);
name=b.toString();//Modified Name
```